# ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'NotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles."

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, onesignal, application-loader

> ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'app.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
>   ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."

**in my app project**

`Always Embed Swift Standard Library = No`

`Embedded Content Contains Swift = Yes`

**in my target**

`Always Embed Swift Standard Library = Yes`

`Embedded Content Contains Swift = Yes`

**in OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension**

`Always Embed Swift Standard Library = No`

`Embedded Content Contains Swift = NO`

when I try to change OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension to YES it displays error that `import OneSignal` is not `No such module 'OneSignal`

OneSignal is written in Swift and should be imported with the use_frameworks!

Answer (score 7):

**OneSignalNotificationService** *target* -> **Build Phases**  -> **run script** :

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then
rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```